# Is it possible to query a query object in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to query my postgres database from django, the query I'm using is

```
s = Booking.objects.all().filter(modified_at__range=[last_run, current_time], coupon_code__in=l)
```

Now I am changing this object of mine in some ways in my script, and not saving it to the database. What I want to know is that, is it possible to query this object now?

say, I changed my variable as

```
s.modified_at = '2016-02-22'
```

Is it still possible to query this object as:

```
s.objects.all()
```

or something similar?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are asking here. `s` is a queryset, it doesn't have a `modified_at` property, or an `objects` manager.

Comment: Anyways, you are using filter which returns a list, s.modified_at will throw an error.

Comment: The filter returns a list, what i meant was that I changed the values within that list (i.e, s).

Comment: What is the usecase of changing the object, not saving it, and then query again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QueryManager is Django's interface to the database (ORM). By definition this means you can only query data that has been stored in the database.

So, in short: "no". You cannot do queries on unsaved data.

Thinking about why you are even asking this, especially looking at the example using "modified_at": why do you not want to save your data?
(You might want to use `auto_now=True` for your "modified_at" field, btw.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
bookings = Booking.objects.all().filter(modified_at__range=[last_run, current_time], coupon_code__in=l)
for booking in bookings:
   booking.modified_at = 'some value'
   booking.save() # now booking object will have the updated value
```